# Java Accessor/Mutator -> Property name

Tags: java, properties

What I am wondering, is there a libarary for Java that allows you to determine the name of a property given an accessor/mutator.

Like so:

```
getValue() -> value 
setAnotherValue(String v) -> anotherValue
```

I'm looking to use this property value with Apache BeanUtils to match the given setter/getter to the corresponding getter/setter respectively.

I know I've seen this behaviour before, but now that I am looking for it, I am unable to find a library that gives me this capabilty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java.beans.Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) is useful for getting that information. You want to use `getBeanInfo()` then from the bean info, you typically want to call `getPropertyDescriptors()` Using the property descriptor you can get the property names and then references to `java.lang.reflect.Method` objects for the appropriate getters and setters if you wish to invoke them.

Good luck.

Comment: This was just the answer I was looking for.  Fits beautifully with Apache PropertyUtils & BeanUtils.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [describe](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29) to get the properties having corresponding accessor methods. To get for a specific accessor method, compare (using regex) from the returned set of properties.

Comment: Close, and I think this would work, but the other answer proved to be more streamlined